# Why does this piece of code redirect to a.php irrespective of the password and username i input?

Tags: php, forms

Code that submits form:

```
</form>
<script>
var user = prompt('Enter username');
var pass = prompt('Enter password');
document.getElementById('user').value = user;
document.getElementById('pass').value = pass;
document.getElementById('form').submit();
</script>
```

Code that validates username and password:

```
   <?php
if($_POST['user'])
{
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    if($user = "root")
    {
    if($pass = "pass")
    {
        header('Location: a.php');
    }
    else
    {
        echo'<b>Access Denied</b>'; 
    }
    }
else
    {
        echo'<b>Access Denied</b>';
    }
}   

?>
```

The valid.php page redicts to a.php even if the username and password I type in the prompt box are not 'root' and 'pass' respectively and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: `if($user = "root")` this is always true statement, because you assign `root` to `$user` successfuly. If you need comparison, you need `==` or `===`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if($user = "root")
```

should be

```
if($user == "root")
```

And so on for others

```
= assignment

== / === comparison
```

You need to correct those in the condition.

Learn more about **[comparison operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)**

Comment: Also mention that `==` checks for equality of value and `===` checks for equality and type, so `1 === 1.0f` is false while `1 == 1.0f` is true.

Comment: yes correct, I have added the link in the answer for better understanding the operators.

Answer (score 1):

Use `==`comparison rather than `=` assignment...normal mistake that happens to all..!!

and you can do it using single `if else` statement

```
if($user == "root"  && $pass == "pass" )
        {

            header('Location: a.php');
        }
    else
        {
            echo'<b>Access Denied</b>';
        }
```